# Calculating date differences between records

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table in our database that various systems report into with timestamp and values. This table is called the data table. (I know, I didn't name it.)

So I'm given the task of going through and find the time differences between the reports for a particular system.

Not knowing how else to go about this, I created a temporary table, such:

```
CREATE TABLE #Readings(
  id            INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  timestamp     DATETIME
)
```

Then I insert all of the readings for a particular system:

```
INSERT INTO #Readings (timestamp)
SELECT ReadingAt
FROM data 
WHERE SenId = 3
ORDER BY ReadingAt
```

Finally, I run my query:

```
select  r1.id, r1.timestamp, datediff(second, r1.timestamp, (select r2.timestamp 
from #Readings r2 where r2.id = (r1.id - 1)))
from    #Readings r1
where id > 1
```

but this returned:

```
101 2011-07-14 04:44:05.443 <null>
102 2011-07-14 04:46:05.443 -120
103 2011-07-14 04:48:05.447 -120
104 2011-07-14 04:50:05.447 -120
105 2011-07-14 04:52:05.447 -120
106 2011-07-14 04:54:05.45  -120
107 2011-07-14 04:56:05.45  -120
108 2011-07-14 04:58:05.45  -120
109 2011-07-14 05:00:05.45  -120
110 2011-07-14 05:02:05.453 -120
```

So I did the following:

```
select  r1.id, r1.timestamp, (select r2.timestamp from #Readings r2 where r2.id = (r1.id - 1))
from    #Readings r1
where id > 1
```

which returned the correct dates.

So, I'm wondering, how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The results you've got look reasonable to me - if you want positive values, just change the order of the second and third operands. What did you *expect* to get?

Comment: The results are always 120 seconds regardless of the time range. That's why they're not reasonable.

Comment: Which is actually the right answer. Whoops. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: what is the actual problem - what output do you expect? you compare id to 1, but your first ID is 101... and -120 is the expected result for diff'ing dates two minute apart when you put the earlier one as first parameter

Comment: What is the question being asked here?

Comment: @Thom Will you ever have a situation where you have nonconsecutive ID's? For example 101,102,104,105,108,109, etc. If so, I think that will break all the suggested queries (maybe not Bassam's- I don't know) and might be something you need to keep an eye out for.

Answer (score 4):

Make it simpler on yourself, don't use subqueries!

```
select
   r1.id,
   r1.timestamp,
   datediff(second, r2.timestamp, r1.timestamp) as TimeBetween
from
   #Readings r1
   left join #Readings r2 on
      r1.id = r2.id+1
where
   r1.id > 1
```

But for what it's worth, the first query is right. Your `datediff` function is the time between the start time and the end time. Ergo, the start time has to be less than the end time. That's why you're getting negatives.

Comment: I had thought of that at one point, but for some reason, didn't try it. When I tried just now, it returned:

101 2011-07-14 04:44:05.443 <null>
102 2011-07-14 04:46:05.443 -120
103 2011-07-14 04:48:05.447 -120
104 2011-07-14 04:50:05.447 -120
105 2011-07-14 04:52:05.447 -120
106 2011-07-14 04:54:05.45 -120
107 2011-07-14 04:56:05.45 -120
108 2011-07-14 04:58:05.45 -120
109 2011-07-14 05:00:05.45 -120
110 2011-07-14 05:02:05.453 -120
111 2011-07-14 05:04:05.453 -120
112 2011-07-14 05:06:05.457 -120
113 2011-07-14 05:08:05.507 -120
114 2011-07-14 05:10:05.51 -120

Comment: @Thom - It is better to do it with a `JOIN`, but the problem is with the order of the columns on your `DATEDIFF`, it should be the other way around. Since every record in your example data are 2 minutes apart, the result is -120 seconds

Comment: @Thom - Edited it to be the correct sign for you--your issue is order in the `datediff` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it all in one query, without any temp tables

```
SELECT T1.ReadingAt, T2.ReadingAt, 
       datediff(second, T2.ReadingAt, T1.ReadingAt) AS TimeBetween
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReadingAt) AS RowNumber, ReadingAt
      FROM data 
      WHERE SenId = 3) t1
      INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReadingAt) AS RowNumber, ReadingAt
       FROM data 
       WHERE SenId = 3) t2 ON T1.RowNumber = T2.RowNumber + 1
```